# Programitcally Creating Azure Service Bus using Asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am trying to programmatically create an Azure service bus, however, I am not sure whether it is possible to create or not.

If it is possible, then it would be very much helpful if someone can describe the way in which it can be created.

Currently, I am trying to create it through asp.net MVC.

Comment: From KrishnenduGhosh : *Do you mean creating the whole service bus resource or queue/topic/subscription within a existing service bus? For the later, you can using service bus management SDK. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management). If you mean creating the service bus resource as a whole, I would like to understand more on the scenario why your application needs to create infrastructure on it's own instead of from a deployment pipeline.*

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend creating infrastructure such as Azure Service Bus via automated steps such as from a deployment pipeline (e.g. from Azure DevOps) using ARM templates or using the Azure CLI if ARM templates are not an option for you. (See here for further documentation on this topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-topic-with-rule)

Although I would usually not recommend it (but then again, I do not know your motives) you can also create namespaces, topics and subscriptions from code. You can find samples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-manage-publish-subscribe-with-basic-features/blob/master/Program.cs